# CSS to change background color in image container

Tags: html, css, image, containers, background-color

Need a CSS to set the background color of image containers to white.  I think my snag is how to call out the specific item to apply the CSS to.  Below works on the site background but not the image containers.

```
body {
  background-color: white;
}
```

I believe this is the box object I'm trying to adjust: document.querySelector("body > div.wrapper > div > div.products.row > div.col-sm-12.col-md-10 > div:nth-child(1) > div.image-wrap")

The gray bars above and below the bike images here need to be white instead of gray: https://www.hermosacyclery.com/bikes/electra/cruiser-attitude.

Thanks,
Steve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to target the **img** tag directly in order to apply the desired style. You can add this CSS to solve the issue:

```
    .products .product .image-wrap img {
       background-color: #ffffff; 
    }
```

Comment: Worked like magic on all the images in our Web store.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what @Edgar has said about using

```
.products .product .image-wrap img {
   background-color: #ffffff; 
}
```

You also need to be aware of the "cascading" part of CSS.
There is another active CSS entry that is overriding the background colour.

```
.slider img,
.products .product .image-wrap img,
.categories .category img, 
.zoombox .images a img, .zoombox .thumbs a img {
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
}
```

Specifically the `.products .product .image-wrap img,` part of that selector group.